# Can an Objective-C object be its own delegate? Is it good programming practice?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, delegates

I know it is possible, but is it really a good programming practice? The idea is to subclass `UIAlertView` and subscribe myself as my own delegate in order to be able to add buttons and block handlers. That way, when I get the `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` I call the block that was passed on.

I hope it's understandable. Is it a good programming practice?

**UPDATE:** Here's my idea of what I was asking https://github.com/ianmurrays/IMAlertView. Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Delegate means to pass responsibility to something else. If the responsibility is the same class then a delegate doesn't make sense.

Comment: When you see subclass**View** you expect to see a view, not a the code handling the clicking because then you can't reuse the view. Likely, you'll be using that with a controller, so that's the natural place to put the handling code in.

Comment: The documentation states that `UIAlertView` does not support subclassing.

Comment: Huh, crap :( Although I'm not modifying its view hierachy.

Comment: Lots of people have already implemented this, so unless you simply want to learn the intricacies of doing it yourself, you might as well use someone else's implementation.  For example, my implementation is here: https://github.com/mayoff/BlockModals

Comment: I was using BlocksKit, but one of its dependencies was making our app crash too often (A2DynamicDelegate).

Answer (score 5):

Yes you are right, any class or object can be a delegate of any other, even of itself. But I would say **it is not a good practice**. You can create other class and delegate it to other. It bifurcates the work implementation and readability is maintained. And in future you can update your code with less labor.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a category to add blocks behaviour to the `UIAlertView`. You can check this [this](https://github.com/jivadevoe/UIAlertView-Blocks).